# Change spring boot server port using code not properties file

Tags: spring-boot, server, port, netty

I want to change the server port using code and not by passing due to properties file, because i have changer the tomcat to netty server.

```
server.port=9999
```

i have used this one and it works, i want the code method.

any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to inject the object EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer in the form of a bean and you can change the container port as below

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            container.setPort(9999);
        });
    }
}
```

hope that would help

Comment: for springboot 2.x, using 'WebServerFactoryCustomizer' replaced